Is this a bug in Whatsapp for ios?
Joining Whatsapp from my new work phone - Downloaded the Whatsapp app version 24.11.85 for ios 17.5.1 iPhone SE Model MHGQ3B/A
When I attempt to register my phone number I am unable to click NEXT at the point you send your phone number to be registered
The text overlays onto the Next button and so it just responds to a URL link in the text and launches my browser. I does not respond to the button.
To check this I tried interacting with the screen with accessibility mode on to identify what actions I can take on the screen and the Next button is not identified as clickable everything else is.
The last update was to the UI - so makes me think somehow the UI got messed up and the button no longer links to actually doing something . Am I correct that it's a bug and how can I contact someone to fix this?
For various reasons I need it to work tonight - so any thoughts of a work around in the meantime ?
Have tried deleting and reinstalling app and restarting phone. Have tried interacting with screen using voice commands.
(That isn't my actual phone number - just a random dummy number and yes I know the leading 0 should not be in there that is not the issue though)



It's not an iOS bug so it's got to be an issue with WhatsApp. Did you contact their app support?

Yes i am saying its a bug in whats app and yes contacted support but getting nowhere fast

There's not much, or anything, people here can do about a poorly designed & tested 3rd-party app. With large, corporate apps like WhatsApp, nothing moves fast.  You'll just have to wait until they update the app to fix it.

I was asking here to see if anyone else has experienced the bug or if in fact it is user error. I am pursuing support to recognise it as a bug. I think I am at least speaking to a human now but the last advice was the classic “turn it off and on again “

I found a solution on iPhone SE by going into Settings -> Display & Brightness and changing Text Size to the smallest setting. This reduced the text above the button just enough to allow a press on the button.

Wow yes that solved it for me. Amazing that the accessibility features could not solve this , yet tbis trick does !

@JudyD You should accept the answer if it solved the problem. Click on the green check mark next to the question.

Ok - This is a great workaround that allows me to complete the task. Not an answer directly but I guess we can infer  the answer to the question “  is it a bug?  “. Yes it is ! I was hoping someone on here would be from WhatsApp and acknowledge it publicly or someone would respond to the part of the question about  a way to get to a human at WhatsApp. However it makes sense for me to  accept the workaround as the answer now.  I am very appreciative of that workaround.

There was a 4-year period where the SE was dropped and app developers probably stopped testing for the smaller screens and hence the bug. I got sick of the lack of app support and got a bigger iPhone but am now back to my original SE after the bigger one died (water ingress). There is defo more app support for small screen these days but sadly the WhatsApp developers dropped the ball this time.
